# JSON to Excel using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, excel, xml

I am trying to export a `Tree Hierarchy in JSON` format(with nested elements) to `Excel`. So far I found out some plugins that help convert `json to xml` file which can be opened in excel. But once opened, it doesn't maintain the hierarchy layout (such as child elements indented slightly to right of the column compared to parent). Are there any plugins out there that already handle this scenario?

I found an article of the same requiring indentation but using JAVA for the conversion, I need the JS equivalent.

[XML to Excel - JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666079/maintaining-hierarchy-from-xml-to-excel-file-java)

Comment: Have you tried importing the json? https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/connect-to-a-json-file-f65207ab-d957-4bf0-bec3-a08bb53cd4c0

Comment: @Olian04 - Never tried that, but the clients need a functionality to export the data from webpage to an excel spreadsheet on button click. Not sure what version excel they will be using, so going through the power query and populating data won't be something they would like to do.

Comment: In that case you could probably build a quick solution your self using something like [`exceljs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs).

Comment: @Olian04 - will that support indenting of data? I tried X2JS plugin, it looks good except it's in flat file format with no indentation. I have a nested hierarchy with around 6-8 levels of children, so it would be nice to have it indented.

Comment: That i don't know.